# Missing comma in JS array literal - Why does this compile?

Tags: javascript

I forgot a comma initializing a 2D array in javascript and, to my surprise, it compiled. E.g.:

```js
amIMissingSomething = [
    [1, 2, 3]
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

console.log(amIMissingSomething) // [undefined, [7, 8, 9]]
```

I expected a syntax error to occur. However, after a whole lot of time, I learned this is valid javascript and evaluates to: `[undefined, [7, 8, 9]]`. What's going on here?

Comment: because the code is seen as `[1,2,3][6]` If you seen it written as `var a = [1,2,3]; var b = a[6];` does it make sense? [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is getting parsed as:

```js
amIMissingSomething = [
    [1,2,3][4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
```

the comma operator returns the last expression so basically:

```js
amIMissingSomething = [
    [1,2,3][6],
    [7,8,9]
]
```

and since the first array doesn't have 7 elements it evaluates to `undefined`

Answer (score 5):

It's interpreted as `array[index]`

See [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3][0]

console.log(a)
```

The result of expession `4, 5, 6` is 6, see [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator)

```js
const arrayChangeHandler = {
  get: function(target, property) {
    console.log('getting ' + property + ' for ' + target);
    return target[property];
  },
};

const originalArray = [1, 2, 3];
const proxyToArray = new Proxy( originalArray, arrayChangeHandler );

proxyToArray[4, 5, 6]
```